# jQuery button click refresh of jqGrid only firing once

Tags: jquery

I have the following code in page.

1. I have entered  the employee id and click the Generate employee button and grid look fine with the data
2. the problem is when i change the employee id and clicks the Generate button again.. this  time  the grid is not refreshing .. it showing old data  only..

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btn_GenerateEmpList").click(function () {
                var firstClick = true;
                if (!firstClick) {
                    $("#EmpTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
                }
                firstClick = false;
                var empId=  $("#txt_emp").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "PLBased.aspx/GetEmpNames",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ empId: empId}),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function (result) {

                        result = result.d;
                        jQuery("#EmpTable").jqGrid({
                            datatype: "local",
                            colNames: ['Emp Name'],
                            colModel: [
                                    { name: "EmpName", Index: "EmpName", width: 80 }
                            ],
                            data: JSON.parse(result),
                            rowNum: 10,
                            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                            pager: '#pager',
                            loadonce: false,
                            viewrecords: true,
                            sortorder: 'asc',
                            gridview: true,
                            autowidth: true,
                            sortname: 'EMPID',
                            height: 'auto',
                            altrows: true,

                        });
                    },
                    error: function (result) {

                        alert("There was some error ");
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: is that button in the grid itself?

Comment: No The button is out side of grid ...

Answer (score 0):

In you ajax callback when it's success add this code :

```
 $("#EmpTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response i have tried it .. but still grid is showing old data only ....

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
 gridComplete:function(){
     $("#EmpTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
 }
```

Comment: Nope .. not working .. i suspect there was a problem with     datatype: "local",

Comment: Thanks  for the replies

I found the solution like below .. just add unload method after successful ajax call

  $("#EmpTable").GridUnload();

and it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Reloading of the grid will not fetch data from the server because Your grid is configured datatype:local. You may have to add the data to the grid using addRowData.